# How to clean a drain in a refrigerator?

Tags: drain, cleaning, refrigerator, clog

We have an old Kenmore fridge/freezer combo. It is slowly leaking water into the bottom of the fridge which is below the freezer. After doing some research we think its likely because of a clogged drain hose. We are not sure how to remove the attachment so we can clean it.
[image]

**How can I remove this black drain without breaking anything so I can clean it?**
[image]

Comment: Do you have water/ice in the bottom of your freezer compartment?  That's usually a sure sign that the drain tube is blocked.  Also, if you remove the panel from the back side/bottom of the freezer (4 screws), you should be able to see the drain tray and the hole that the drain tube attaches to.

Comment: Yes water pools in the bottom of the fridge over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experience, from inside the fridge you can clean it out with a cable tie (flexible long thin piece of plastic).

Insert tie and rotate.

It is unlikely to be blocked all the way down, just at the join at the top.

Comment: I was able get in through the back. I removed the drain line coming out from the bottom of the trap and was able to clean it from there. I didnt have to go through the front.

Answer (score 1):

On my Samsung, I had to remove the back cover and flush out the hose from the refrigerator box to the drain pan. Or try to snake it out from above.

Comment: Same with both my Frigidaires.